# Problem with setting state hook conditionally in Memory Game

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a memory game and have some big problems with maintaining logic when two tiles don't match. I'd probably know how to do this if we could use hooks conditionally. My code looks like this:

```js
var choiceArray = [];
const Board = () => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(Array(12).fill(false));

  const handleClick = index => {
    setIsHidden(
      isHidden.map((hidden, hiddenIndex) =>
        index === hiddenIndex ? !hidden : hidden
      )
    );

    choiceArray.push(index);
    console.log(choiceArray);

    if (choiceArray.length === 2) {
      if (animalArray[choiceArray[0]] === animalArray[choiceArray[1]]) {
        console.log("dupa");
        choiceArray = [];
      } else {
        setIsHidden(
          isHidden.map((hidden, hiddenIndex) =>
            index === hiddenIndex ? !hidden : hidden
          )
        );
      }
      choiceArray = [];
    }
  };

  const renderButton = index => {
    return (
      <Button
        icon={animalArray[index]}
        isHidden={isHidden[index]}
        onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
      />
    );
  };
```

I declared a choice array globally, to avoid problems with previous/current state. (I don't know if it's a good practice tho). Anyway I wanted to set isHidden boolean of both tiles to false if the icons don't match (expression inside else is of course wrong, just a placeholder). But according to Rules of Hooks I can't do that. In fact, I think i shouldn't even set the state inside event handler. Could anyone suggest me a way to go around this restriction? Or maybe some other logic, which will help me sort things out in this project?
Thank you in advance

Comment: There's no problem with calling setIsHidden behind a condition. It's only a problem to call useState behind a condition.

Comment: Oh, really xd. That changes everything. Thank you sir